# References in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a simple counter for a game. I want to be able to increment the fire, water and earth attributes using a method which takes a string and an int as arguments.

I am however not sure whether the following would work. I am not sure the ints within the elements array would point to the original attribute of the same name or if it would just make a copy of it in the array.

```
class TypeCounter{
    int fire = 0;
    int water  = 0;
    int earth  = 0;
    string[] elementNames = { "fire", "water", "earth"};
    int[] elements = {fire, water, earth};

    public void AddTo(string element, int val){
        int keyIndex = Array.FindIndex(elementNames , element);
        elements[keyIndex] += val;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do the following:

```
TypeCounter counter = new TypeCounter();

public Run(){
    print counter.fire;
    counter.AddTo("fire", 1);
    print counter.fire;
}
```

I would expect an output of `0` for the first print statement and `1` for the second, when I execute the Run() method.

Comment: consider using a dictionary for this.

Comment: you have fields and arrays - this code is a mess.

Comment: See also: [Value and Reference Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/4d43ts61.aspx)

Comment: "Pointers in C#, when are they used?" - This has *nothing* to do with Pointers.

Comment: Seconding Daniel's suggestion...it very much looks like you're wanting what a Dictionary<> would do...a Dictionary<string, int>, to be precise.

Comment: Just execute and see what happens.

Comment: `"I am however not sure whether the following would work."` - What happens when you test it?  `"I would expect an output of 0"` - What happens when you test it?  Stack Overflow is a very poor replacement for a compiler.

Comment: `print counter.fire;` - let's assume that would be legal C# code, then still fire is not accessible here.

Comment: "consider using a dictionary for this." - paired with an Enum containing the legal key values that the dictionary shall accept. If you insist on an API like `AddTo( counterKey, value )`, that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method will increment the items in the `elements` array, not the `fire`, `water`, `earth` fields.